Laplace Transform of Renewal function and Renewal Density
I am trying to clarify the relation between the Laplace Transform of a Renewal function $L_M(s)$ and the Laplace transform of a Renewal density $L_m(s)$. (Notation used in Stochastic Processes: Theory for Applications, Gallager)
From the derivation, I know the relation is $L_M(s)=L_m(s)/s$. However, if it is $L_M(s+a)$, should it be $L_m(s+a)/s$ or $L_m(s+a)/(s+a)$?
Thanks
